# How to rename the title page of Google Maps and hide the browser tab when inactive using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser-tab

how to rename the title page of Google Maps without affecting the search bar using pure/native JavaScript? Coz when I tried to change it the search bar is affected, whatever title that I put, it will also display in search bar, how can avoid to display the title in search bar of Google Maps? And how can I hide or close the browser tab if the user switch into another tab using pure JavaScript?

Example: When the tab is open the Google Map, and the user switch into another tab, the Google Map tab will be hide or closeThank you

I'm Googling many hours but nothing found, all scripts that I saw are made in JQuery not in native/pure JavaScript

Comment: what is "title page of Google Maps"?

Comment: title page of Google Maps, that display in the tab,e.g when you see this tab, it appears my question as title of this tab